# How to prove that $c^Tx(\mu)$ is strictly decreasing with $\mu$ in interior point method for LP

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the Primal-Dual problem,

(P)min $c^Tx$

s.t. Ax = b, x $\geq 0$

(D) max $b^Ty$

s.t. $A^Ty + s = c$, s $\geq 0$

The log-barrier function for (P) is :

min $c^Tx - \mu \sum_{i=1}^n ln(x_i)$

s.t. Ax = b, x > 0

How to prove that if $\mu > \mu^{\prime}$, then $c^Tx(\mu) > c^Tx(\mu^{\prime})$, where $x(\mu)$ is the optimal solution of log-barrier function with parameter $\mu$.

Comment: can you prove it by contradiction?

Comment: I think constradiction is a little difficult.